# getRuntime().exec(command) hung

Tags: java, runtime

I am executing a command which returns nothing, it instead creates a zip file in a directory. Whenever there is some problems executing the command, the application will enter a hung state. I saw plenty of info saying that I should also delete my ErrorStream, but none of the code I already seen on StackOverflow has been able to help me in my use case.
Please bring your attention to my code below.

In the code, I run a command and then the java application inputs an ID and Password into the fields required and then the program begins.

```
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SomeCommand);
    try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
         Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()) ) {

        CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(80);
        int tries = 2;

        while (process.isAlive()) {

            while (reader.ready() && reader.read(buf) > 0) {
                System.out.println(buf.flip());
                buf.clear(); 
            }
            tries--;

            if (tries == 0) {
                writer.write(p);
                writer.flush();
            }

            if (tries == 1) {
                writer.write(h);
                writer.flush();
            }

            while (!reader.ready()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (!process.isAlive ()) {
                    // Code to update UI to reflect progress
                    process.destroy();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    SubmitController.logger.warningMessage("Error>>> CommandController");
    progressIndicator.isVisible();
}
```

Comment: What is that some command ?

Comment: @Sambit The command is to run a bash script.

Comment: Is that bash script running correctly and providing response ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when you read the process' output? you really mean to just throw it away?

Comment: @Renato At different times in the execution it gets hung at different spots. Now I believe it is because of me not reading and clearing the ErrorStream, however I don't really know how.

Comment: the way you're reading the inputstream is highly unusual... have you seen how it's usually done? maybe check this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-processbuilder-api

Comment: @Renato I will give it a look, but I choose this route because I first input two values to the command then I wait for the output to finish.